# f:setPropertyActionListener not working when simpleModal working

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, simplemodal

I have the next code:

```
<h:commandLink value="#{bean.lastName}" onclick="$('#popDiv').modal(); return false;">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{personController.person}" value="#{bean}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

The problem is that to make the modal panel (of SimpleModal) to not open and close immediately i have to use "return false" when "onclick" occurs. But "return false" makes f:setPropertyActionListener not work.
What can be done to make them both work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Can you do something like:

```
<h:commandLink value="#{bean.lastName}" onclick="openModal(event);">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{personController.person}" value="#{bean}" />
</h:commandLink>

function openModal(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#popDiv').modal();
}
```

Comment: Won't work since the `f:setPropertyActionListener` runs at server side, not client side. So the HTTP request associated with the `h:commandLink` has to go to the server side anyway to get it to run.

Comment: BalusC - what do you propose?

Answer (score 1):

you need to work with

```
<p:commandLink value="#{bean.lastName}" onclick="openModal(event);">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{personController.person}" value="#{bean}" />
</p:commandLink>
```